# How enable Lightning App Builder?

Tags: aura, lightning-apps

I was googling unsuccessfully.

I've created Aura components without any problem, but I can't figure out how enabled this:

[image]

I'm trying to enable that feature in a Dev Winter 15.

Comment: For anyone reading this later, the Lightning App Builder is GA with Summer '15. See: 
http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_mobile_salesforce1_newfeat_appbuilder.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be very precise ,You will need to request salesforce to provide you the access to this builder .since its in pilot you will need to raise a case to get early access to this for your instance.

Comment: can you please provide path or screenshots it will be usefull

Comment: You will need to contact salesforce to get it enabled .

Answer (score 1):

You can [follow this link](http://bit.ly/lightning-org) to open a new developer edition.

Answer (score 0):

The Lightning App Builder is a new declarative tool for Admins to use to build pages that customize the behavior of Salesforce1. This feature is in pilot for Winter '15.

Comment: I know what Lightning App Builder is. I'm just asking how to enable that feature in a winter's 15 dev. Thxs any way

Comment: If it is a Pilot feature, you will have to open a case with salesforce support.

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for :)
Where you find that I should open a case ?

Comment: Yes, You should open a case with the salesforce support.